# Calling a class for testing - Python

Tags: python, arrays, vector

First off this is a homework assignment I'm working on, but I really just need help on an error.

So the project is to implement a vector (a list in all but name for this project), using the Array class. The array class I'm using can be found [here](https://github.com/docsis/Data.Structures..Using.Python.code/blob/master/2/array.py).

My error is that every time I try to call my code to test it, specifically the **getitem** and **setitem** functions, I wind up with an error stating:

```
builtins.TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

Below is the class I'm currently building, (so far it seems that only **len** and **contains** are working).

```
class Vector:
    """Vector ADT
    Creates a mutable sequence type that is similar to Python's list type."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructs a new empty vector with initial capacity of two elements"""
        self._vector = Array(2)
        self._capacity = 2
        self._len = 0

    def __len__(self):
        """Returns the number of items in the vector"""
        return self._len

    def __contains__(self, item):
        """Determines if the given item is stored in the vector"""
        if item in self._vector:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __getitem__(self, ndx):
        """Returns the item in the index element of the list, must be within the
        valid range"""
        assert ndx >= 0 and ndx <= self._capacity - 1, "Array subscript out of range"
        return self._vector[ndx]

    def __setitem__(self, ndx, item):
        """Sets the elements at position index to contain the given item. The 
        value of index must be within a valid range"""
        assert ndx >= 0 and ndx <= self._capacity - 1, "Array subscript out of range"
        self._vector[ndx] = item

    def append(self, item):
        """Adds the given item to the list"""
        if self._len < self._capacity:
            self._vector[self._len] = item
            self._len += 1
```

I'm trying to call the code by either typing:

```
Vector()[i] = item
```

or

```
Vector[i] = item
```

However, trying:

```
Vector[i] = item
```

Gives me the error, and:

```
Vector()[i] = item
```

Doesn't really seem to do anything other than not cause an error.

Comment: Maybe you just want to use a `list` instead of that Array class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your `Vector` class. Try:

```
vector = Vector()
vector[0] = 42
```

The error means that you are trying erroneously to assign to the `Vector` class itself, which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *replace* method instead of assigning a value.

Answer (score 0):

`Vector` is a class; `Vector()` creates an instance of that class.

So

```
Vector[i] = item
```

gives an error: `Vector.__setitem__` is an instance method (runs against an instance of a class, ie an object), not a classmethod (runs against a class). (You could in theory make it a classmethod, but I have trouble picturing a use case where that would make sense.)

On the other hand,

```
Vector()[i] = item

# 1. creates a Vector() object
# 2. calls {new_object}.__setitem__(self, i, item)
# 3. doesn't keep any reference to {new_object}, so
#     (a) you have no way to interact with it any more and
#     (b) it will be garbage-collected shortly.
```

Try

```
v = Vector()
v[i] = item

print(item in v)    # => True
```